# How do I configure mod_wsgi with python that has been built from source code?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I want to build mod_wsgi against a Python which I have built myself from source code in Ubuntu. (You can see specifically how I built it in [How would I build python myself from source code on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097161/how-would-i-build-python-myself-from-source-code-on-ubuntu))

I tried running this from within the mod_wsgi-3.3 directory:

```
$ sudo ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs \
  --with-python=/usr/local/share/man/man1/python2.7.1
```

which was probably pretty naive since I know that python2.7.1 is just a text file and not an executable, which the command probably expects. I ended up getting a bunch of Permission denied messages even though I ran it in sudo.

So how would I build mod_wsgi against a Python that has been built from source code?

Also, are there any inherent issues I should expect in the future in having the Python I built and the default Ubuntu Python co-existing in separate directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-python=/usr/local/share/man/man1/python2.7.1
```

I would assume you would want to use:

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7.1
```

I think you want to tell mod_wsgi to use the path to the python executable rather than the man page

Comment: You don't need to use 'sudo' for configure or make, only make install.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: Oh you are right, I just left his original commands I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is pretty clear about what was required.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide#Configuring_The_Source_Code