# Django - No module named _sqlite3

Tags: django, python-2.7, sqlite, django-models, django-admin

I have django 1.4 installed on my rhel 5. By default rhel 5 has python 2.4 in it but to use django 1.4 I manually installed python 2.7.3
The development server is running fine but when I create a new project and after changing the settings.py file as :

'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
'NAME': '/home/oracle/Desktop/test1/my.db'

Now when I give python2.7 manage.py syncdb command, I get the error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
line 443, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
line 382, in execute
   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
line 261, in fetch_command
   klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
line 69, in load_command_class
   module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
line 35, in import_module
   __import__(name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py",
line 8, in <module>
   from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model,
emit_post_sync_signal
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py",
line 6, in <module>
   from django.db import models
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py",
line 40, in <module>
   backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py",
line 34, in __getattr__
   return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
line 92, in __getitem__
   backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
line 24, in load_backend
   return import_module('.base', backend_name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
line 35, in import_module
   __import__(name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
line 31, in <module>
   raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or
sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either
pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named
_sqlite3
```

Please suggest the way out?

Comment: Do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114946/how-do-i-set-up-sqlite-with-a-django-project and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3 help?

Comment: i have this error with Python 3.4, when i choose python 3.5 i dont have this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the [django.db.backends.sqlite3](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py#L27), it tries to

```
try:
    try:
        from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as Database
    except ImportError:
        from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
except ImportError as exc:
    from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
```

So one of the modules named **[sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/)** or **[pysqlite2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite/)** is not installed.
Try to install them

```
$ pip install sqlite3 # or pysqlite2
```

**Update**

`sqlite3` and `pysqlite2` are part of Python, therefore these two packages are not in [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org) anymore.

Comment: This is now a part of Python (if compiled with this option), so there isn't any sqlite3 package anymore in pip repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlite3 and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite2

Comment: @Dereckson I've updated the answer regarding to your comment. Thanks

Comment: @AlirezaSavand I am using django 1.10.3 with python 3.5.2 but am still facing this error. Any solution?

Comment: @AlirezaSavand Same here

Answer (score 25):

You may also have compiled python by hand with no sqlite development library installed

So, do

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3
```

Then, re-install python

test by entering

```
python
>>> import sqlite3
```

Comment: Note that pyenv install <version> will (as of today) warn about missing libzip-devel and readline, but not about missing sqlite3-devel.

Comment: If you plan to do any debugging, you might also want to install the debug libraries using `apt-get install libsqlite3-0-dbg`.

Comment: Faced a missing sqlite3 for common django commands on a fresh centos7 installation. We had python2.7 altinstall to have the latest python on-bpard. Installing sqlite3 via yum and recompiling python from source saved us!

Answer (score 5):

I got very similar error message when I tried to run the Django development server:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): dlopen(/Users/Rubinous/Projects/Jiiri2/jiiri_venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/Rubinous/Projects/Jiiri2/jiiri_venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
Reason: image not found
```

I solved this by installing `pysqlite` Python module with `pip install pysqlite`.

Comment: in case of python 2.6 and earlier version need to install pysqlite as a separate lib.

Answer (score 5):

On MacOSX 10.9 (Mavericks), I had to run this command:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include; LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib; pip install pysqlite
```

I used homebrew to install sqlite3.

```
brew update; brew install sqlite
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did to get it to work.

I am using pythonbrew(which is using pip) with python 2.7.5 installed.

I first did what Zubair(above) said and ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Then I ran this command:

```
pip install pysqlite
```

This fixed the database problem and I got confirmation of this when I ran:

```
python manager.py syncdb
```

Answer (score 3):

[sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) is part of the Python from versions 2.5 onwards. Install this lib:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Or you can also try installing the Python-dev package.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with python 2.6.8 built from source on Red Hat (but this probably holds for other versions on other OS).

My problem was solved by installing sqlite-devel (Red Hat) **before** configuring and building python (or do `config.status --recheck` in your build directory, followed by `make` and `make install`.

Answer (score 1):

**FreeBSD10**: for **python3.5**

```
pkg install py35-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

MordicusEtCubitus's answer is correct. Can't upvote you yet as am a newbie.

Just to add to your answer, on fedora(23) run the following command to install instead.

```
sudo dnf install libsqlite3x-devel libsqlite3x
```