# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named _sqlite3

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlite, django-1.8

I tried re-installing python 2 in my environment.

Re-installed pip, setuptools

when I try to run python manage.py runserver it throws the error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named _sqlite3
```

I tried installing sqlite 3 , its already installed

I tried installing pysqlite2 , its already installed

both python 2 and installed in my ubuntu 16.04, django version = 1.8.X

Still unaware of what cause the error?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784132/django-no-module-named-sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users:
Download the source file of the Python version that you need, from [source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source). Extract the folder somewhere, cd into the folder,

```
./configure
make
make install
```

this should fix your issue.
(This can be done outside VE, i just had the same issues with python 3.4)