# How to install Python 3.5.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

When I run `apt-get -y install python3`, it installs Python 3.5.2. How can I install Python 3.5.5?

Just to mention that I run these commands in Docker:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip wget default-jre
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install virtualenv
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. You'll need to find a repository that has that version and add the repository in your container build script.  There's a nice explanation of how to add a repository for apt-get on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get)
2. Build it from source, using the [official repository](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-355/). This is explained on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097241/3084820) albeit for a different Python version

Also, if you may be able to find a docker image that already has Python 3.5.5 in it on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).  I didn't see one with a quick search, but it might be worth a closer look.