# How do I build the python source code to current directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I am trying to set up python on a system I do not have root access to and do not have internet connected. I was able to get the python source code on the machine and now I want to compile it and I want the executable and all the files to be in my current working directory (ie `/home/me/python/<install here>`).

How do I get this done?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097161/how-would-i-build-python-myself-from-source-code-on-ubuntu

Comment: There is a tool called pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv , which is quite nice.
However in order to compile python you need quite some dependencies in your OS. For ubuntu for example: 
 build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev

If all these packages are installde, then compiling python should be fine. Just follow the instructions